# How to open links both in an external browser and in-app within a WebView for Android

Tags: android, android-webview

I'm trying to create both links to open internally within the my app's WebView and others which open externally within whichever default browser. I have seen previous questions and answers regarding but none seem to be working and I think the solutions may be outdated?

Any suggestions  of how best to achieve this would be appreciated. Opening links within the app is working fine, it's just getting links to open in an external browser where applicable. Maybe some kind of class or url parameter check? I haven't managed to get either to work so far.

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private WebView myWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        myWebView.loadUrl("https://website.com/");
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (myWebView.canGoBack()) {
            myWebView.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any condition when you want to open an external web browser and when want to show it in the webview?

Comment: @rahat - yes ideally I would like to open some page links within the webview and some page links outside of it within an external browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                if(wantToOpenExternal){
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                    String title = "Select a browser";
                    Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(intent, title);
                    startActivity(chooser);
                    return true;//cancel the current load
                }
                return false;//continue the current load
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks @rahat. That worked although I had some trouble with if statement 'wantToOpenExternal'. I swapped that bit for url.contains("external=true") and now it will only open the urls I want to in the internet browser if I add that parameter to the link and the rest still open within the webview as I wanted. Thanks again.

Comment: @Dan, Welcome Pal, how about some upvotes